# Issues to send emails on a javascript PHP post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having problems to send emails, but only on this code. I have other php sending emails, but this is the only one called by AJAX. Might be a asyncronic issue?

Also, I have tryed to put some 
echo 'console.log("it's inside");';
on the php file, but its never triggered. Also in the console from the browser it doesn't show any error.

I'm clueless.

I added the return to the php but it didn't solved the issue.

```
function addTurno() { 
    var vnombre = $("#updt_nombrep").val();
    var vapellido = $("#updt_apellidop").val();
    var vnombrecompleto = vnombre + " " + vapellido;
    var vdesosocial = $("#updt_osocialp").val();
    var email_p = $("#updt_emailp").val();
    var email_n = $("#hidden_emailn").val();
    var vtexto = $("#updt_texto").val();
    var vedad = $("#updt_agep").val();
    var vfechac = $("#turno_datepicker").val();
    var vhordes = $("#turno_timepickerd").val();
    var vhorhas = $("#turno_timepickerh").val();
    var vidnutri = $("#hidden_id_nutri").val();
    var T = 'T';
    var resto = '-07:00';
    var vfechad;
    var vfechah;

    var vgcalendar = $("#hidden_updt_glink").val();

    var ano = vfechac.substr(6, 4);
    var mes = vfechac.substr(3, 2);
    var dia = vfechac.substr(0, 2);
    var vfechacedit = ano+'-'+mes+'-'+dia;

    vfechad = vfechacedit.concat(T, vhordes, resto );
    vfechah = vfechacedit.concat(T, vhorhas, resto );


    enviaEmail(vidnutri, vnombre, vapellido, vfechac, email_p, email_n, vtexto, vhordes, vhorhas );
    guardaTurnoGoogle(vgcalendar,vfechad,vfechah,email_n,email_p,vnombrecompleto,vtexto ) ;

}

function enviaEmail(vidnutri,vnombre, vapellido, vfechac, email_p, email_n, vtexto, vhordes, vhorhas ){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "ajax/sendEmailTurno.php",
      data: { 
        vidnutri : vidnutri,
        vnombre: vnombre, 
        vapellido: vapellido, 
        vfechac: vfechac, 
        email_p: email_p, 
        email_n: email_n, 
        vtexto: vtexto, 
        vhordes: vhordes,
        vhorhas: vhorhas
        },
      success: function(data, status){
        console.log("Email enviado correctamente");
        },
      async:false
    }); 
}
```

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $emaipaciente = $_POST['email_p'];

    if(isset($_SESSION["id"]) && isset($_POST["vidnutri"]) ){

        if ( $_POST["vidnutri"] == $_SESSION["id"] ) {

            $subject = "Turno con Nutricionista";
            $from = "From: ". $_POST['email_n'];
            $from .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $from .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
            $message =
            "
            Estimado" . $_POST['vnombre'] . " " . $_POST['vapellido']. ",
            Recuerde que el " . $_POST['vfechac']. " tiene turno desde las " . $_POST['vhordes']. " hasta las " . $_POST['vhorhas']. " con la nutricionista" . $_SESSION['nombre'] $_SESSION['apellido']. " matrícula " . $_SESSION['matricula'] . ".

            ". $_POST['vtexto']. "

            Gracias, saludos.
            ";

            return mail($emaipaciente,$subject,$message,$from);

        }else{
            $_SESSION['mess'] = 'Error de sesión: logueado en múltiples cuentas?';
            header("Location: ./index.php?modo=TerminarSesion");
        }

    }else{
        $_SESSION['mess'] = 'Error de sesión: no logueado';
        header("Location: ./index.php?modo=TerminarSesion");
    }

?>
```

Comment: Never ever use `async:false`. It is a horrible practice and is deprecated by browser vendors. You should be seeing deprecation warnings in browser dev tools console

Comment: i'va changed the  ´´async´´ because it was not working... i change it back and still not work

Comment: Also doing redirect in php won't cause page redirect when request is ajax. `echo console.log(...)` in php would only be returned as text in ajax  and would never execute. You need some messages echo'd in each conditional and no redirects then log the `data` in `success` to make sure your conditionals are working for starters

Comment: go you mean like:
`
try{
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "ajax/sendEmailTurno.php",
      data: { 
        vidnutri : vidnutri,
        vnombre: vnombre, 
        vapellido: vapellido, 
        vfechac: vfechac, 
        email_p: email_p, 
        email_n: email_n, 
        vtexto: vtexto, 
        vhordes: vhordes,
        vhorhas: vhorhas
        },
      success: function(data, status){
        console.log("Email enviado correctamente");
        },
      async:false
    });
 }
 catch(error){console.log(error);}
    });
`

Comment: Echo  a different message in each `if/else` and nothing else. Then in ajax success `console.log(data)`. If that `console.log()` fails you aren't getting a successful request. INspect the full request in browser dev tools network also. Can see what gets sent, what gets received , status, headers etc

Comment: Could you please recomend a tool? Im usimg just notepad++. Thanks

Comment: Tomorrow i will try with echo. Also i will try putin messages to the session to see

Comment: i have tryed to add messages to session (PHP) and to console.log (JavaScript) but it's like its not entering at all... i've runed out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: the was a missing dot (concatenate) in the PHP file:  `$_SESSION['nombre'] $_SESSION['apellido']`

What helped me was on the console -> network , watching it was a "Internal Server Error" so then i thought it should be a server side error.

Hope my mistake helps someone, and thanks @charlietfl